# Atmosphere PubSub with Jersey 2

Tags: java, atmosphere

I am trying to implement pub-sub logic using Atmosphere with Jersey 2.8. My understanding is that atmosphere-jersey only supports Jersey 1.x. What do I need to implement pub-sub in Jersey 2? Which methods do I need to use and which annotations beyond @AtmosphereService:

```
@Path("/chat/{topic}")
@AtmosphereService(
        dispatch = false,
        interceptors = {AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.class, TrackMessageSizeInterceptor.class},
        path = "/chat/{topic}",
        servlet = "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer")
public class Jersey2Resource {
    private
    @PathParam("topic")
    Broadcaster topic;
```

I understand that this question is pretty broad but most of the Atmosphere samples seem to rely on Jersey 1.x.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is old, but did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No. We gave up on Atmosphere and simply provided a refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this interceptor AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor and write Get method instead. You can write a new interceptor by extend that interceptor or following the its structure